# Creating multiple objects "x" distance away from each other

Tags: java

I am trying to finish my code for an assignment I have, but I'm stuck on the last component. I need to create "stars" (small yellow square objects) in the "sky"... a grid of 5 rows of 10 stars. I am in a beginner java class, and I am supposed to being using methods such as star.moveHorizontal() or star.moveVertical(). All of the relevant posts I've searched for have been too complex or out of my comprehension.

I think that I would need to create an array? We haven't even covered that in class... And then have each "star" be x distance (the first star) + 30 units to the right. Then t continue that trend until there are 10 stars in a row. And then get four more rows of 10 stars.

Here is the code I've create for just one star (in the upper left of my window):

```
Square s1 = new Square();
s1.makeVisible();
s1.changeColor("yellow");
s1.changeSize(5);
s1.moveVertical(-100);
s1.moveHorizontal(-270);
```

Then I tried to create an array for a square class... I honestly have no idea if that's even legal.

```
Square[] starArray = new Square[10];
for ( int i=0; i<starArray.length; i++) {
starArray[i] = new Square();
```

But then I don't understand how I can call each star and make them appear... Please help. I feel so out of my depth. I've tried to research this and try new things for over 2.5 hours now. I will answer any questions you have to the best of my ability. Thank you

Comment: Where do you have to show the starts ? in simple console or Swing

Comment: There is no need to create an array, unless you need to reference the squares at a later stage.

Answer (score 1):

If you can make a single star appear and haven't learned about arrays yet, I don't think that is the answer your teacher is looking for. The point of an array is to be a container so you can reference the objects again. If you don't need to go back to the stars in the future, just create them and set their values in a loop.

```
// Set defaults for spacing and start positions
int horizontalStartPosition = 10;
int horizontalSpacing = 30;
int verticalStartPosition = 10;
int verticalSpacing = 30;
// Outer loop creates the 4 rows
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    // Inner loop creates each row
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        // Create the next star in the row
        Square s = new Square();
        s.makeVisible();
        s.changeColor("yellow");
        s.changeSize(5);
        // Move the star to the correct vertical position for the current row
        s.moveVertical(verticalStartPosition + i * verticalSpacing);
        // Move the star to the correct horizontal spacing for the next star
        s.moveHorizontal(horizontalStartPosition + j * horizontalSpacing);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that it better to put  `s.makeVisible();` at the end. Also you need to add `s` to its container.

Comment: @c0der I thought about doing that as well but since the OP didn't share any of the other code I thought it best not to alter their code for displaying the star. I didn't add `s` to a container since that wasn't in the scope of the problem as I read it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understand, you would want to call a method which would basically place a star in the grid for you.
I am not fully sure of what you mean, but here is what I can offer you:

You'll want to create a method for placing a star.

```
private static int X_SPACING = 30;
private static int Y_SPACING = 20;

public Square placeStar(int x, int y){
    // This is the same code that you had before.
    Square sq = new Square();
    sq.changeColor("yellow");
    sq.changeSize(5);
    sq.moveVertical(-y); // Where Y is the distance from the TOP LEFT.
    sq.moveHorizontal(-x);

    return sq;
}

public ArrayList<Square> makeRow(int columnsAmount, int y, int startX){
    ArrayList<Square> squares = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < columnsAmount; i++)
        squares.add(placeStar(startX + (X_SPACING * i), y));

    return squares;
}

public ArrayList<Square> makeGrid(int rowsAmount, int columnsAmount){
    ArrayList<Square> rslt = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < rowsAmount; i++)
        rslt.addAll(makeRow(columnsAmount, (i * Y_SPACING), 0);

    return rslt;
}
```

Basically, calling "makeRow" *should* create a row of [rowsAmount] stars, which are all separated by [X_SPACING] pixels.
Then, makeGrid will call makeRow multiple times adjusting [y], and this will make you a grid. Feel free to adjust any value in the code.

EDIT: I've added a makeGrid function, and changed a few variables in the makeRow as I mistyped them. I made the functions return an ArrayList, but you shouldn't need them, only if your teachers later ask to modify them later, or something.

I hope this helps, don't hesitate to ask more questions.
Sneling.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. You can use a 2D array with 5 rows and 10 columns. Try something like this:

```
int numColumns = 10; //the number of columns in the array
int numRows = 5; // the number of rows in the array
Square[][] starArray = new Square[numRows][numColumns]; // the array itself
final int DIST_X = 10; //the distance between columns (use final because this value should not change)
final int DIST_Y = 10; // the distance between rows (use final because this value should not change)
int y = 0; // the initial row's vertical displacement 

for ( int i=0; i<numRows; i++) {
    int x = 0; // the initial columns horizontal displacement
    for ( int j=0; j<numColumns; j++) {
        starArray[i][j] = new Square(); //define the square
        starArray[i][j].moveHorizontal(x); // move it x units horizontally
        starArray[i][j].moveVertical(y); // move it y units vertically
        starArray[i][j].makeVisible(); //show the square
        x += DIST_X; //update your horizontal displacement so the next column shows up in the correct position
    }
    y += DIST_Y; //update your vertical displacement so the next row shows up in the correct position
}
```